# Getting value of req and resolvedUrl as undefined from GetServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js

I'm using next js version  "next": "^12.1.4",
node version     "@types/node": "^14.14.6",

I have made a function called getServerSideProps which has paramters req and resolvedUrl and at first render of page I'm getting these values as undefined and when I refresh the page it will get the values.

As the req and resolvedUrl are comming as /undefined/undefined/

so I tried by apply conditions with these values but still it wont works.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons why req and resolvedUrl are coming as undefined in your getServerSideProps function. Here are some possible scenarios and solutions:

1. Incorrect usage of getServerSideProps: getServerSideProps can only be used in page components, not in non-page components. If you're using getServerSideProps in a non-page component, it won't work stackoverflow.com. If this is the case, you should move getServerSideProps to the page component.

```
    // In your page's getServerSideProps function
    export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
      // Your logic here
    }
```

2.Incorrect handling of the context parameter: The context parameter of getServerSideProps contains the req and resolvedUrl properties. Make sure you're accessing these properties correctly [nextjs.org](https://nextjs.org).

```
    export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
      const { req, resolvedUrl } = context;
      // Your logic here
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Bahriddin both these conditions are satisfied even though at first render req and resolvedUrl getting undefined.